# Managing many exceptions in Erlang cowboy without deeply nested trees

Tags: erlang

In my `cowboy` (Erlang) application, I have a handler called `projects_from_json`. This takes a JSON POST request as input and should create a database entry from this. Then, it should respond with a success message or the correct error message to the user.

I started with two exceptions that could occur (simplified):

```
projects_from_json(Req=#{method := <<"POST">>}, State) ->
    {ok, ReqBody, Req2} = cowboy_req:read_body(Req),
    try
        Name = parse_json(ReqBody),
        % Continuation of happy path
        db:create_project(Name)
    catch
        error:{badkey, Key} ->
            % return error message about invalid JSON
            % [<<"Key \"">>, Key, <<"\" does not exist in passed data">>]
        throw:duplicate ->
            % return error message about duplicate name
            % [<<"A project with name \"">>, Name, <<"\" already exists">>]
    end
```

Already in this case, this did not work, because `Name` is not safe in the second catch clause (since it comes from the try clause and could potentially be unset). I also could not move the call of `db:create_project(Name)` outside of the `try`, because then again `Name` would not be safe to be used.

Since there were some more exceptions and errors to be handled, I ended up with a very deeply nested situation (follows below).

My first idea would be to move stuff into own functions, but most of the code is error handling and as far as I know I can only handle the error by returning a tuple from the `projects_from_json` handler.

So here follows my nested mess. In total, I currently want to handle three error situations:

- InvalidValue: The project name sent by the user contains invalid characters
- DuplicateValue:  A project with the same name already exists
- MissingKey: User did not supply all required keys

Code:

```
projects_from_json(Req=#{method := <<"POST">>}, State) ->
    {ok, ReqBody, Req2} = cowboy_req:read_body(Req),
    try
        Name = project_name(ReqBody),

        case validate_project_name(Name) of
            invalid ->
                molehill_respond:respond_error(<<"InvalidValue">>,
                    <<"The project name can only consist of ASCII characters and numbers, and dash in the middle of the word.">>,
                    400, Req2, State);
            ok ->
                {ok, Conn} = moledb:connect_from_config(),

                try
                    moledb:create_project(Conn, Name),
                    Data = prepare_project_json(Name),
                    molehill_respond:respond_status(Data, 201, Req2, State)
                catch
                    throw:duplicate_element ->
                        molehill_respond:respond_error(<<"DuplicateValue">>,
                            erlang:iolist_to_binary(
                                [<<"A project with name \"">>, Name, <<"\" already exists">>]),
                            409, Req2, State)
                end
        end
    catch
        error:{badkey, Key} ->
            molehill_respond:respond_error(
                <<"MissingKey">>,
                erlang:iolist_to_binary(
                    [<<"Key \"">>, Key, <<"\" does not exist in passed data">>]),
                400, Req2, State)
    end.
```

Is it possible to restructure this to a clean form where all possible errors are on a similar indentation level at the end of the function?

[`molehill_respond`](https://github.com/molescrape/molehill/blob/1d7b500173d4b661b539078ac175e46154d9cc4d/src/molehill_respond.erl) is a helper module I wrote to simplify the creation of my JSON return messages, [`moledb`](https://github.com/molescrape/molehill/blob/1d7b500173d4b661b539078ac175e46154d9cc4d/src/moledb.erl) is a helper module that executes all the SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first attempt (without changing any of your functions nor the semantics of your handler) would be:

```
projects_from_json(Req=#{method := <<"POST">>}, State) ->
    try
        {ok, ReqBody, Req2} = cowboy_req:read_body(Req),
        Name = get_project_name(ReqBody),
        {ok, Conn} = moledb:connect_from_config(),
        Data = get_project_json(Conn, Name),
        molehill_respond:respond_status(Data, 201, Req2, State)
    catch
        error:{badkey, Key} ->
            molehill_respond:respond_error(
                <<"MissingKey">>,
                erlang:iolist_to_binary(
                    [<<"Key \"">>, Key, <<"\" does not exist in passed data">>]),
                400, Req2, State);
        error:{error, Label, Message, Status} ->
            molehill_respond:respond_error(Label, Message, Status, Req2, State)
    end.

get_project_name(ReqBody) ->
    Name = project_name(ReqBody),
    case validate_project_name(Name) of
        invalid ->
            erlang:error({
                error,
                <<"InvalidValue">>,
                <<"The project name can only consist of ASCII characters and numbers, "
                    "and dash in the middle of the word.">>,
                400
            });
        ok ->
            Name
    end.

get_project_json(Conn, Name) ->
    try
        moledb:create_project(Conn, Name),
        prepare_project_json(Name)
    catch
        error:duplicate_element ->
            erlang:error({
                error,
                <<"DuplicateValue">>,
                erlang:iolist_to_binary(
                    [<<"A project with name \"">>, Name, <<"\" already exists">>]),
                409
            })
    end.
```

I basically moved pieces of your code from `projects_to_json/2` into its own functions so you can keep your main one tidier.

But you might have noticed that my new functions still have a lot of code for encapsulating the errors. If you can get `validate_project_name/1` and `prepare_project_json/1` to raise the errors in the proper format themselves instead of returning `invalid | ok`, this gets reduced to…

```
projects_from_json(Req=#{method := <<"POST">>}, State) ->
    try
        {ok, ReqBody, Req2} = cowboy_req:read_body(Req),
        Name = project_name(ReqBody),
        validate_project_name(Name),
        {ok, Conn} = moledb:connect_from_config(),
        moledb:create_project(Conn, Name),
        Data = prepare_project_json(Name)
        molehill_respond:respond_status(Data, 201, Req2, State)
    catch
        error:{badkey, Key} ->
            molehill_respond:respond_error(
                <<"MissingKey">>,
                erlang:iolist_to_binary(
                    [<<"Key \"">>, Key, <<"\" does not exist in passed data">>]),
                400, Req2, State);
        error:{error, Label, Message, Status} ->
            molehill_respond:respond_error(Label, Message, Status, Req2, State)
    end.

%% @doc this function may raise an error like {error, binary(), binary(), 400..499}
validate_project_name(Name) ->
    …

%% @doc this function may raise an error like {error, binary(), binary(), 400..499}
prepare_project_json(Name) ->
    …
```

Basically, the idea is to include as much information as you need on the error itself, so… instead of failing with `duplicate_element`, you fail with `{error, …, …}` so that the outer loop can catch that. If you can’t decide on how your functions will fail, just wrap them up in other functions that will translate the errors/results into the expected form.